# Why does the data come back as undefined?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm not understanding why the data is coming back as undefined. It knows there is something there but the value is not being shown. Am I forgetting to do something in the main function? Thanks in advance to whom may solve my dilemma.

Here is the current output I'm getting:
[image]

Here is what I need the output to render:
[image]

Here is the code for my employee.js:

```
$(function() {
    ajaxCall("Get", "api/employees", "")
    .done(function (data) {
        buildTable(data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        errorRoutine(jqXHR);
    }); // ajaxCall

});

// build initial table 
function buildTable(data) {
    $("#main").empty();
    var bg = false;
    employees = data; // copy to global var
    div = $("<div id=\"employee\" data-toggle=\"modal\"data-target=\"#myModal\" class=\"row trWhite\">");
    div.html("<div class=\"col-lg-12\" id=\"id0\">...Click Here to add</div>");
    div.appendTo($("#main"));
    $.each(data,function(emp){
        var cls = "rowWhite";
        bg ? cls = "rowWhite" : cls = "rowLightGray";
        bg = !bg;
        div = $("<div id=\"" + emp.Id + "\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" class=\"row col-lg-12" + cls + "\">");
        var empId = emp.Id;
        div.html(
            "<div class=\"col-xs-4\" id=\"employeetitle" + empId + "\">" + emp.Title + "</div>" +
            "<div class=\"col-xs-4\" id=\"employeefname" + empId + "\">" + emp.Firstname + "</div>" +
            "<div class=\"col-xs-4\" id=\"emplastname" + empId + "\">" + emp.Lastname + "</div>"
            );
        div.appendTo($("#main"));  
    }); // each
} // buildTable


function ajaxCall(type, url, data) {
    return $.ajax({// return the promise that '$.ajax' returns
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true
    });
}
```

Here is my Controller method code:

```
// GET api/<controller>
[Route("api/employees")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    try
    {
        EmployeeViewModel emp = new EmployeeViewModel();
        List<EmployeeViewModel> allEmployees = emp.GetAll();
        return Ok(allEmployees);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest("Retrieve failed - " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(data)` what are you getting back exactly?

Comment: Could you show us the exact untouched ajax reply ?

Comment: what does EmployeeViewModel look like?  Is it possible that the property name case is different from what you used in javascript?  I'm seeing Firstname, Lastname as opposed to FirstName, LastName etc

Comment: @LeoNix that's one of the things I first checked, the variables are the same

Comment: have you stepped through the javascript code in the browse debugger to see what your data looks like?

Comment: @LeoNix oddly enough I have 10 objects(which is correct) and when I expanded on the the objects in the debugger it showed the proper values. So the data is there but its not showing. Perhaps I missed a step in the main JQuery function when calling my ajaxCall function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the callback is the index, the value is in the second parameter:

```
$.each(data,function(index, emp){
```